# ReflectionClass without executing other method functions

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following function where I only want to pull the relationships of a model:

```
public static function definedRelations(): array
    {
    $model = new static;
    $relationships = [];

    $class = new \ReflectionClass($model);
    foreach($class->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $method)
    {

        if ($method->class != get_class($model) ||
            !empty($method->getParameters()) ||
            $method->getName() == __FUNCTION__) {
            continue;
        }

        try {
            $return = $method->invoke($model);

            if ($return instanceof Relation) {

                $relationships[$method->getName()] = [
                    'name' => $method->getName(),
                    'title' => ucwords(implode(' ', preg_split('~^[^A-Z]+\K|[A-Z][^A-Z]+\K~', $method->name, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY))),
                    'type' => (new \ReflectionClass($return))->getShortName(),
                    'model' => (new \ReflectionClass($return->getRelated()))->getName()
                ];
            }
        } catch(\Exception $ex) {}
    }

    return $relationships;
}
```

My problem is that when the ReflectionClass is called, it is executing the functions of that model. I am not as familiar with ReflectionClass', and I am not sure how I would "ignore" the following function on the model when executing the ReflectionClass?:

```
public function recalculateInvoicing(){
    $invoice = $this->invoices()->firstOrNew(['charge_type_id' => 13]);
    $invoice->amount = $this->citations->where('is_active', 1)->sum('amount');
    $this->invoices()->save($invoice);
    
    return $this;
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Is this just to avoid this specific function? You can add `$method->getName() === 'recalculateInvoicing'` in one of the conditions that triggers the `continue;`

Comment: I’m not too familiar with Laravel, so can you explain your desired outcome more? You are calling `invoke` which does what it says.